# RpivotTable Hiding or removing the Line Chart legend

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

TL;DR Question: Can I remove the Legend to be displayed when using the Line Chart option in the RpivotTable package in Rstudio/Shiny?

Hi all,

I am extremely new to Stack Overflow and also R, Rstudio and Shiny a real noob.

I absolutely adore the rpivotTable package!

I am probably being a bit too ambitious but I am hoping to use Shiny, and rpivotTable package to replicate dashboards I had created previously in Excel utilizing multiple pivot tables and connected to slicers...

Unfortunately the data sets/data frames I am using have a large amount of variables, when I construct Line Charts using the rpivotTable package the legend fills the entire screen instead of displaying the Line Chart :(

My rows contain over 1000 different exception codes hence the Legend being too large to be displayed....

Sample Code:

```
  output$pivtbl2 <- renderRpivotTable(rpivotTable(data = DataSet(),
                                                 aggregatorName = "Sum",
                                                 vals = "Count",
                                                 cols = "ExceptionDate",
                                                 rows = "ErrorCode",
                                                 menuLimit = 1200,
                                                 rendererName = "Line Chart"))
```

Sorry if this question has been answered elsewhere I have spent a bit of time searching, or the answer is really obvious I am very new to R.

Or any other suggestions of packages to use or research to achieve what I am trying to do will be appreciated!

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Line Chart" in rpivotTable is a C3 chart.  You can hide the legend, and provide other options for a C3 chart by passing a named list entry with a `c3` key to the `rendererOptions` argument of `rpivotTable()`.  Currently you also need to call provide an extra line of code to get this to work, as outlined in [this issue on the rpivotTable GitHub page](https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable/issues/92).

For your case, it would be:

```
output$pivtbl <- renderRpivotTable({
  tbl <- rpivotTable(
    data            = DataSet(),
    aggregatorName  = "Sum",
    vals            = "Count",
    cols            = "ExceptionDate",
    rows            = "ErrorCode",
    menuLimit       = 1200,
    rendererName    = "Line Chart",
    rendererOptions = list(
      c3 = list(
        legend = list(
          show = FALSE
        )
      )
    )
  )

  tbl$x$params$rendererOptions <- tbl$x$params$rendererOptions[[1]]

  tbl #return value
})
```

The available options to pass to C3 charts are listed here: https://c3js.org/reference.html

Comment: Thankyou dtownley,

This solution works perfectly! :)